# sftp login with private key & public key no username and domain given

Tags: ssh, rsa, sftp, public-key-encryption, private-key

My client send me today a public and a private rsa key to login to the sftp server. Is it possible to derive the domain and username from these files, or did he simply forget to mention them? He send me an email with the keys in the attachement and said i could find all information in the attached files.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the public key.  At the end of the key, there should be a string that looks like this:

```
= user@host
```

Assuming he created the key on the server, that's the host name.